# How to avoid delays caused by cv2.undistort?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, real-time, camera-calibration

I am using OpenCV in python to track an object. first, I should calibrate the camera and after finding the properties I should find the precise location of the object and it should be real-time

I found this code

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
.
.
.

# undistort
dst = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
```

so based on this code i should undistort every frame, and it is time-consuming,
is there any way to set the parameter of camera and then use the machine vision?
or any other way?

Comment: @Ash thanks for your comment, your right, first i get the parameters such as ret, mtx and other attributs and save them, then i want to do object tracking, so i do cap.read() and get the frame, so after that, i should undistort the frame, right?  i taught this line would add delay , thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `undistort` is that it recomputes the mapping from distorded to undistorted pixels every time it is called. You need to compute the coordinate transform only once. You can just compute it using `cv.initUndistortRectifyMap` which returns the corresponding mapping (see the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a) here). Then you can use the function [cv.remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4).

Comment: so now for every frame i should do remap? does this solve the problem for real time application? thanks again

Comment: @miladzzz Techinically yes, that should be real-time. However as you probably know python is not usually the best option for real-time applications, so if you have a lot of constraintes (e.g. low-capacity hardware etc) it might do things in C++ (pytorch for example has a nice and easy to use api).